# How to get customer's addresses using CustomerId?

Tags: magento2, customer-address

I am trying to get all the addresses of a customer using below code. But here I am not able to fetch all the details. If I try to print the array **$customerAddres** it give me memory exhausted error in terminal.

```
$customer = $this->_customers->load(3);
    $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
    }
    foreach ($customerAddress as $customerAddres) {
        echo $customerAddres['street'];
    }
```

If anyone can help me to get complete addresses of a customer please let me know.

Comment: at first, you need to get customer from repository using `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::getById` method.

Comment: You can also try with an alternative way, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-customer-address-list-by-customer-id-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

Try following way:

```
protected $customerRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
```

And now

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById(2);
/** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $address */
foreach ($customer->getAddresses() as $address) {
    print_r($address->getStreet());
}
```

Comment: I want all the fields name listed in this array. Can I get this?

Comment: its object of Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address, open this class and make your array calling getXXX method.

Comment: How to get address id of customer?

Comment: @sohel Just wanted to know that $address->toArray() is not working anymore in magento version 2.3.x Right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get customer address.

```
$customerId = 3;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);
$customerAddress = array();

foreach ($customerObj->getAddresses() as $address)
{
    $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
}

foreach ($customerAddress as $customerAddres) {
    echo $customerAddres['street'];
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but here I am not able to print the array $customerAddres. Why?

Comment: have you confirm that, the customer with id 3 have address?

Comment: Yes, this $customerAddres['street'] prints the value, but if I try to print the complete array it gives memory exhausted array.

Comment: what you have try to print the complte array?

Comment: if answer got help you, please accept it as solution so it help other in community as well.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get the answer. I have tried to print $customerAddres. But it gives me error of memory exhaust. Every time I am trying to print any big array it says memory exhaust.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67039/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-gaurav-agrawal).

Comment: I have tried your solution which we have discussed, but it didn't worked for me. Then I have tried to print log using: $this->_logger->log(100, json_encode($options));